# My PHP code on the local server (Xampp) has the expected result, but on the online server it doesn't

Tags: php, json, response

Good afternoon people.

I created some functions in php / MySQL that returns a json object, As you can see in the code below.

File tweets.php (Class)

```
    <?php
class Tweets {
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = 'tweets';

    public $id;
    public $text;
    public $created_at;

    // Constructor
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function readAll() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY created_at ASC";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }

    public function create() {
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " SET tweet_id = :tweet_id, text = :text, created_at = :created_at";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $this->tweet_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->tweet_id));
        $this->text = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->text));
        $this->created_at = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->created_at));

        $stmt->bindParam(':tweet_id', $this->tweet_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':text', $this->text);
        $stmt->bindParam(':created_at', $this->created_at);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function delete() {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function deleteAll() {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name;

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function search($keywords, $start, $end){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE text LIKE ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?, ?";
    
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    
        $keywords=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($keywords));
        $keywords = "%{$keywords}%";
    
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $keywords);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
        $stmt->execute();
    
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function count(){
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM " . $this->table_name . "";
    
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
        return $row['total_rows'];
    }
}
?>
```

File getTweets.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require_once '../config/config.php';
include_once '../config/database.php';

include_once '../objects/tweets.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$tweets = new Tweets($db);

$keywords = isset($_GET["s"]) ? $_GET["s"] : "";
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : '';
$end = isset($_GET['end']) ? $_GET['end'] : '';

$stmt = $tweets->search($keywords, $start, $end);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num > 0) {
    $tweet_arr = array();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);

        $tweet_item = array(
            "text" => $text,
        );

        array_push($tweet_arr, $tweet_item);
    }

    http_response_code(200);
  
    echo json_encode($tweet_arr);
} else {
     http_response_code(404);
  
     echo json_encode(
         array("message" => "Nao foi achada nenhuma promoção.")
     );
}
?>
```

The functions work perfectly on my local web server (Xampp), but when I upload to the final web server (Online), I have the response status 200 OK but without any json object.

As you can see in the images below, the first is the response from the local server and the second from online. What could be happening?

[PrintScreen Postman - local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ppCM.png)

[PrintScreen Postman - online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eropI.png)

Comment: Is the DB on the "final web server" populated?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same as the one on the local server

Comment: Maybe try to execute a simple SQL query and see what does it return.

Comment: I put the same query in phpMyAdmin and it worked without a problem in the MySQL of the online server, what I am not understanding is because I don't even have errors and nothing about results, this is more strange.

Comment: I'll edit my question and put the complete code to see

Comment: In the local example you include start and end query parameters that are excluded in the online example. Not sure if relevant, but thought it worth noting. - After further review I actually believe this is your problem. The query in `search()` will end at `LIMIT` and return nothing.

Comment: I'd also review the headers each response contains. Just because there are 11 in each case doesn't mean they're the same.

Comment: If you receiving 200 OK there is a big chance your if ($num >0) condition from getTweets.php is fulfilled. I suggest you debug each row inside it. You can do it by doing var_export of arrays/objects or by returning any string to see if while loop, for example, executed. Step by step you will finally find what is wrong with your code.

Comment: TCooper I saw it, but even with all the parameters it doesn't work

Comment: @Akhmed When I call var_export from the variable $tweet_arr I get the result that should have. I think the problem is in json_encode, but I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

There could be errors that aren't being displayed, try adding the following code to the top of 'getTweets.php' and see if you get any PHP Warnings/Errors

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: While I agree with your methodology, this is better suited as a comment to improve the question

Comment: I've already activated the error display, but that's the point, there are no errors in the code, it just doesn't return the json and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are not passing the same parameters to the online test in Postman, you have "start" and "end" missing, and it seems that you are not handling them in the search() method.

Comment: I saw it, but even with all the parameters it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that you have a different default charset on the live sever vs local

Check that you connection string contains the charset

```
mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8;
```

Answer (score -1):

After reading the PHP manual a lot I decided to create a function to handle the result. I did these two functions below, I hope it helps other people with the same problem that I had.

```
function safe_json_encode($value){
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') >= 0) {
        $encoded = json_encode($value, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    } else {
        $encoded = json_encode($value);
    }
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            return $encoded;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            return 'Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            return 'Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            return 'Unexpected control character found';
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            return 'Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $clean = utf8ize($value);
            return safe_json_encode($clean);
        default:
            return 'Unknown error';
    }
}
    
    
function utf8ize($mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) {
        return utf8_encode($mixed);
    }
    return $mixed;
}
```

Call:

```
safe_json_encode($tweet_arr);
```